# How to animate the bezier line?

Tags: animation, bezier, compass-geolocation

We have a compass in our app and for the needle we are using an image. Which appears very pixellated... 
It is possible to use a bezier line for the needle instead of a image?
If so how can i get it to rotate - like a compass needle, and for that line to react and move dependant to location changes?Can anyone please assist us with this, thanks.

Comment: The only answer without more details is: "probably?". What platform is your app on? What are you using to draw? Vectors and high density bitmaps are indistinguishable depending on size and resolution, so how high/low quality is your image? How are you rotating it? etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't have to rotate bezier path itself. You can apply affine transform to context to achieve necessary rotation.